# What is the equivalent function of MySQL's FOUND_ROWS() in Firebird?

Tags: firebird

I'm familiar with MySQL but not with Firebird.

I want to change my PHP page, from MySQL into Firebird query, but I have some difficulty during change command `FOUND_ROWS()`. What is the equivalent function of `FOUND_ROWS()` in Firebird?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to @Andrei K. answer.

**Answer to your question:** There's **no equivalent** in Firebird for FOUND_ROWS() MySQL function/statement.

**Workaround**: If you deadly want to know that number of rows, ask the engine to run a new query to compute the number of rows present for a special version of the first query.  For simple queries, [@Andrei K. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231313/whats-the-same-function-of-found-rows-in-firebird/4232369#4232369) is accurate, but for the general case, including queries with group by and having clauses use a query like this:

```
select count(*)
  from (your original query here) q1;
```

You have to exclude the first/skip and order by clauses if present in that original query.  So, for a query looking this:

```
select first 10 skip 20 pd.productcode, extract(year from ph.purchasedate) year, sum(pd.quantity) year_quantity
  from purchase_details pd
       inner join purchase_header ph
          on ph.id = pd.purchase_id
 where ph.cancelled = 0
   and ph.salesman = 10
 group by pd.productcode, extract(year from ph.purchasedate)
having sum(pd.quantity) > 1000
 order by sum(pd.quantity) desc;
```

the found_rows equivalent query will be:

```
select count(*) 
  from (
        select pd.productcode, extract(year from ph.purchasedate) year, sum(pd.quantity) year_quantity
          from purchase_details pd
               inner join purchase_header ph
                  on ph.id = pd.purchase_id
         where ph.cancelled = 0
           and ph.salesman = 10
         group by pd.productcode, extract(year from ph.purchasedate)
        having sum(pd.quantity) > 1000
       ) q1
```

From my experience, this works for 99.9% of the queries.

**Warning** This approach is very inefficient, use at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in Firebird to know how many rows would return query without running the query and fetching all the data or running query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <your tables and conditions go here>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using this `FOUND_ROWS()` to show something like *showing Y rows out of X rows*, see if your new version of the page can do without that information.  The way with Firebird, reading the documentation appears to be, to run the query without the `LIMIT` first and then with the `LIMIT`.  `LIMIT` being MySQL, not sure what is it called in Firebird.  Then there is the `SQL_CALC_ROWS` you should translate from MySQL to Firebird.